# How to store an array of images in Firebase Storage all under 1 path using iOS Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimage, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have 2 views, ViewOne and ViewTwo.

Inside ViewOne there are 4 imageView outlets and a postButton. Once a user presses the postButton all the images will be sent to Firebase Storage and then from there they will be retrieved to be shown in ViewTwo.

Inside ViewTwo there are also 4 ImageView outlets to receive the images posted to Firebase Storage from ViewOne.

Using Firebase Storage I don't see anyway to store multiple images inside Storage all under the same path. I understand how to store 1 image per post to Storage and then access it, but not multiple images.

How do I post multiple images as an array in Storage to be kept under 1 path(ViewOne)? How do I then access all of those images(ViewTwo)?

Btw I got the awesome code (the custom function) for viewTwo from Brian Voong via Youtube: https://youtu.be/b1vrjt7Nvb0

This is the class that the image url strings will go into. I didn't bother putting the init.

```
class ImageData: NSObject{
var imageOneURL: String?
var imageTwoURL: String?
var imageThreeURL: String?
var imageFourURL: String?
}
```

This is imageViewOne. I didn't add in the ImagePicker delegates because it seemed unnecessary but I how know how to use them.

```
import Firebase

ImageViewOne:UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var imageViewONE: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewTWO: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewTHREE: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewFOUR: UIImageView!

var images = [ImageData]()

@IBAction func postButton(sender: UIButton){

//Unigue string for the images to be loaded under their own path
let uniqueImageIDPath = NSUUID().UUIDString

//Firebase Storage Ref
let storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(uniqueImageIDPath)")

//Firebase Image to be stored. This is where I need help to store all the images at once.
if let myImages = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageViewONE.image!, 0.1){ 
    storageRef.putData(myImages, metadata: nil, completion: {

                        (metadata, error) in

                        if error != nil{
                            print(error?.localizedDescription)
                        }

    if let myImageString = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{

        let imageData = ImageData()
        imageData.imageOne = myImageString
        self.images.apped(imageData)

        let values = ["imageOneURL": imageData.imageOne, "imageTwo":"?", "imageThree":"?", "imageFour":"?"]

        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
        ref.updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: {

                (error, user) in

                if error != nil{
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

This is viewTwo

```
import Firebase

ViewTwo: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var imageViewONE: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewTWO: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewTHREE: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageViewFOUR: UIImageView!

var imageOne: UIImage?
var imageTwo: UIImage?
var imageThree: UIImage?
var imageFour: UIImage?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

    ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
            (snapshot) in

            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]{
            let imageURLStr = dict["imageOneURL"] as? String
            self.loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(imageURLStr)
    }
}

//Custom Function
func loadImageUsingCacheWithURLString(urlString: String){

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {

            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                if let displayImage = UIImage(data: data!){

                    self.imageOne = displayImage!
                    self.imageViewOne.image = self.imageOne
                }

            })

        }).resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns Firebase won't let you store arrays of anything. After you get the metadata url for each image your going to have to save each one individually inside FBDatabase and FBStorage.

Comment: Can you explain how to do?

Comment: @EDISONJ which part do you want to know exactly?

Comment: How to store array of image in firebase storage?

Comment: @EDISONJ use a loop to store them in a dictionary then store it inside firebase